# The property <PropertyName> could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Hello I want to send userClaims to database and the property type is object,When in package manager console I run the : add-migration command it's give me this error :The property 'ServiceLog.Claims' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Could you please tell me how I can resolve that? thanks a lot.

```
public object Claims { get; set; }
 private async Task<ServiceLog> LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            ServiceLog logMetadata = new ServiceLog
            {
                Claims = context.User
            };
            return logMetadata;
        }
```

I wanted to the object type mapped into sql server database with efCore ORM,but It gives me this error : The property 'ServiceLog.Claims' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: `object` is a base type for a Reference type variable. How do you propose to store that in a database column? Typically something like that could be stored as either serialized text or as a JSON column. In the entity, Claims can be declared as a `string` then use a `Claims = JsonConverter.Serialize(context.User)` to write the data.

Comment: Actually `object` is the ultimate base type for all types including value types as well as reference types.